# Upload image to wordpress via Android

Tags: android, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am creating an image application in which I am trying to implement the feature to directly upload the photos to wordpress website after successful authentication. I am unable to find anything about this implementation on Android so any kind of help would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [url](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/) it's explain clearly !

and

All you thing is

1-Api to Upload image to web server(host)

2-Send request to Server

3-Need php programming

4-save data in database (It's not necessary)

Hope it help